# Why does my multiprocessing code stop working on large data sets?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to calculate the Moran's Index for a square matrix of features (`Information_Gains_Matrix`) and a corresponding square weights matrix (`Weights_Matrix`). For each feature in `Information_Gains_Matrix` I would like to calculate the Moran's Index while the `Weights_Matrix` is fixed.

As such I am trying to use multiprocessing pool.map to go along each feature of the `Information_Gains_Matrix`. I can make code do this in various ways on small test data sets. However, when I use the actual large data set, the code runs, but then the CPU usage drops to 0%, the process hangs, and nothing is released.

I have tried using globals and shared variables in case it is a memory issue, and I have tried using different queue methodologies in case it can be fixed that way, but I have had no success. The below code is one of these examples that works on small data sets but not on large data sets.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import RawArray, Pool, Lock
from functools import partial 
import numpy as np

## Set up initial fake data

Information_Gains_Matrix = np.random.uniform(0,1,(22000,22000))
Weights_Matrix = np.random.uniform(0,1,(22000,22000))

## Function I want to parallelise.  
def Feature_Moran_Index(Chunks,Wij,N):   
    Moran_Index_Scores = np.zeros(Chunks.shape[0])
    for i in np.arange(Chunks.shape[0]):
        print(Chunks[i]) # Print ind to show it's running
        Feature = Information_Gains_Matrix[Chunks[i],:]    
        X_bar = np.mean(Feature)
        if X_bar != 0:
            Deviance = Feature - X_bar
            Outer_Deviance = np.outer(Deviance,Deviance)
            Deviance2 = Deviance * Deviance
            Denom = np.sum(Deviance2)
            Moran_Index_Scores[i] = (N/Wij) * (np.sum((W * np.ndarray.flatten(Outer_Deviance)))/Denom)
    return Moran_Index_Scores

## Set up chunks inds for each core.
Use_Cores = (multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2)
Chunk_Size = np.ceil(Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[0] / Use_Cores)
Range = np.arange(Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[0]).astype("i")
Chunk_Range = np.arange(Chunk_Size).astype("i")
Chunks = []
for i in np.arange(Use_Cores-1):
    Chunks.append(Range[Chunk_Range])
    Range = np.delete(Range,Chunk_Range)

Chunks.append(Range)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    W = RawArray('d', Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[0] * Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[1])
    W_np = np.frombuffer(W, dtype=np.float64).reshape((Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[0], Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[1]))
    np.copyto(W_np, Weights_Matrix)
    N = Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[0]
    Wij = np.sum(Weights_Matrix)  
    with Pool(processes=Use_Cores) as pool:
        Results = pool.map(partial(Feature_Moran_Index, Wij=Wij,N=N), Chunks)

Moran_Index_Score = np.concatenate(Results)
```

I have no loyalty to this method, if anyone can help me parallelise the calculation of the Moran's Index across the features in any way, I would greatly appreciate it as I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It is a memory issue. Have you tried making the `Information_Gains_Matrix` and the `Weights_Matrix` `RawArray`s?

Comment: Yea I have, same problem. I also figured that I didn't need to do it for the Information_Gains_Matrix, since pool.map only sends a single vector of the matrix to each worker?

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is the size of the Outer_Deviance matrix, and that you can get away without constructing it explicitly. (I'll write an answer later when I'm at the computer.)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, I'll investigate. Looking forward to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Feature_Moran_Index`, `Deviance` has shape `(22000,)`, and `Outer_Deviance` has shape `(22000, 22000)` and uses 3.8GB of RAM.

The quantity

```py
np.sum(W * np.ndarray.flatten(Outer_Deviance))
```

equals

```py
np.sum(W_np * Outer_Deviance)
```

equals

```py
Deviance @ W_np @ Deviance
```

After replacing the first expression with the last one, and removing the definition of `Outer_Deviance`, your program runs to completion with memory usage of c. 11GB.

Comment: Yea this works, makes sense, and is elegant. Thank you very much Ben.